# current source with op-amp+NMOS

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, feedback

this is a closed loop feed back circuit in order to make a precise current source.
 [image]

my first question is about R23. haw much it should be?  i think it is
better to just mounted a 0R resistor and reduce the error of voltage drop on this resistor due to Ib of op amp. but i'm not sure about this. i would be grateful for any advise.

my second question is about R15 and C11. these are not mounted . should i keep them not mounted?

Comment: If you were using an op-amp with substantial bias current, you would want R23 = R17 || R20. But with the 100 pA input bias of AD8629, this probably doesn't matter.

Comment: That's really a current *sink*, not a current *source*.

Comment: If your circuit is stable under all expected load conditions and you're happy with the transient response, then R15 and C11 probably could disappear.

Comment: You have not specified the MOSFET, and you need to. A lot of MOSFETs have a maximum Vgs(th) of 4 volts, which this circuit cannot provide.

Comment: Also, with voltage reference specified, your circuit is a 45 mA sink, not a 20 mA source.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if R23 was about 170\$\Omega\$ (1000||220 -10) to balance both the low bias currents and the effect of impulses coming out of the inputs.

As in the comments, the R15/C11 affect the phase margin. If you feed your current source a step input and it overshoots or oscillates then you may wish to add C11 to control that. C11 is probably necessary unless the MOSFET is a very small one, as that op-amp gets twitchy with very little capacitive loading. I think R15 would be better in series with C11, but it's usually not necessary unless you're really interested in fast response times.

Comment: sorry i don't understand you by "unless the MOSFET is a very small one" can you explain what do you exactly mean?

Comment: Low gate charge, gate capacitance. Not physically small. You can get SOT-23 MOSFETs rated at ~100mA  to ~8A, for example.